# How to access ObjectAtIndex in tabBarController with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, viewcontroller

i used to say in obj-c

```
[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
```

but now in swift no ObjectAtIndex any more

```
self.tabBarController.viewControllers.ObjectAtIndex
```

---

**Update**

ok i am gonna make it simple lets consider i have tabBarController it contains 2 object 
[FirstViewController,SecondViewController] 
and i am trying to make a delegate between the object 
here is the code to set the delegate

```
var Svc:SecondViewController = self.tabBarController.viewControllers[1] as SecondViewController!
Svc.delegate = self
```

when i Run , i got this error  0x1064de80d:  movq   %r14, %rax and no console error is showing up

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your code is OK:

```
var svc:SecondViewController = self.tabBarController.viewControllers[1] as SecondViewController!
svc.delegate = self
```

... however you can omit `!` mark at the end and `:SecondViewController` type definition since it can be inferred by the cast:

```
var svc = self.tabBarController.viewControllers[1] as SecondViewController
```

The problem appears because you try to cast to the wrong class.
Try to print to debug log name of the class of object at `[1]`; add this before your cast to check the class name:

```
let vcTypeName = NSStringFromClass(self.tabBarController.viewControllers[1].classForCoder)
println("\(vcTypeName)")
```

**UPDATE:**

As we figured out in comments, you should cast received view controller to `UINavigationController`:

```
var nc = self.tabBarController.viewControllers[1] as UINavigationController
```

Later you can examine `nc.viewControllers` property and see if for instance its `topViewController` is `SecondViewController`:

```
if nc.topViewController is SecondViewController {
    var svc = nc.topViewController as SecondViewController
    // your code goes here
}
```

Comment: console print `UINavigationController`
and now i should pass the UINavigationController first right ?

Comment: It means that at the 1-st position in your `viewControllers` array you have `UINavigationController` which is obviously not `SecondViewController` class that you use for the cast. That is why you get the error. Do you have your `SecondViewController` class instance wrapped inside navigation view controller?

Comment: yeah i have a UINavigationController before both first and second viewController

Comment: Thanks. Save my day +1.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `objectAtIndex` in swift, just use the `subscript` operator:

```
self.tabBarController.viewControllers[1]
```

Comment: i got this noob error when i use [1] `0x1064de80d:  movq   %r14, %rax`

Comment: Are you sure there are objects in that `viewControllers` array?

Comment: yeah sure i have 4 object

Comment: Can you update your question with some more context? It kind of sounds like you're now getting a separate error, but it's hard to tell with just the one line of code. Also do you get any errors in the debug console when it crashes?

Comment: do you have any other suggestions ?

Comment: Not offhand. Do you have more of a stack trace than just that little bit of assembly?

Comment: look new update if i put ? to unrape `var Svc:SecondViewController? = self.tabBarController.viewControllers[1] as? SecondViewController`
it works but when i try to set the delegate it fails even if i say `Svc?.delegate = self`

Comment: try self. tabBarController.viewControllers![2] as! UIViewController